# formal smoothness and McQuillan formal schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, deformation-theory

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, $A\rightarrow B$ be a continuous map of weakly admissible topological $k$-local algebras.
We assume that it is formally smooth and topologically of finite type in the sense of https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0ALL

does it imply that $B\simeq A[[t_1,..,t_r]]$ for some $r$? If $A$ and $B$ are both noetherian, this is well-known, so the issue is about a generalisation in a non-noetherian setting.